# Why is the standard enthalpy of formation temperature-dependent in JANAF tables?

Tags: physical-chemistry, enthalpy, temperature

I'm unsure why $\Delta_\mathrm{f}H^\circ$ within the [NIST-JANAF Thermochemical Tables](https://doi.org/10.18434/T42S31) [1] is temperature-dependent. Wouldn't the $\Delta_\mathrm{f}H^\circ$ represent the enthalpy of formation at the *reference temperature* (298.15 K) by default? If not, what does it represent?

The following screenshot of the [online page for water](https://janaf.nist.gov/tables/H-064.html) is provided as an example:

> [image: JANAF H2O Table Screenshot]

EDIT:
I believe my point was missed, so I will provide another example.
The following is Equation 13.17b within *Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics*
$$ Q - W = \sum_P n \left( \bar{h}_f^\circ + \Delta \bar{h} - \bar{R} T_P \right) - \sum_R n \left( \bar{h}_f^\circ + \Delta \bar{h} - \bar{R} T_R \right) $$

If I wanted to evaluate the $\bar{h}_f^\circ + \Delta \bar{h}$ term for gaseous water in a hypothetical reaction at a temperature of 800 K, how would I do so?

Would it be (-241.826 + 18.002) kJ/mol or (-246.443) kJ/mol?

#### Reference

1. Thomas C. Allison. *NIST-JANAF Thermochemical Tables - SRD 13*, **2013**. DOI: [10.18434/T42S31](https://doi.org/10.18434/T42S31).
2. Michael J. Moran “Reacting Mixtures and Combustion.” Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics, Wiley, S.l., 2020, pp. 519–519.

Comment: In context of standard enthalpies of formation, there is no standard temperature. More at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_enthalpy_of_formation

Comment: [What is the difference between ΔfH and H-H° in NIST–JANAF tables?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/108738)

Comment: @andselisk, see my edit. That other post did not answer my question, but I wasn't clear with what I was asking.